# Build static Qt with icu and webkit using MinGW on Windows

Tags: windows, qt, mingw, qtwebkit, icu

I want build static Qt with webkit support. I compiled icu with the help of [this manual](https://wiki.qt.io/Compiling-ICU-with-MinGW).

But I can't compile it. I am getting a lot of errors like this:

```
mingw32-make[3]: Entering directory 'D:/Qt/static/src/qt-everywhere-opensource-src-5.5.0/qtbase/src/tools/qdoc'
D:/Qt/Tools/mingw492_32/bin/mingw32-make -f Makefile.Release
mingw32-make[4]: Entering directory 'D:/Qt/static/src/qt-everywhere-opensource-src-5.5.0/qtbase/src/tools/qdoc'
g++ -static -static-libgcc -Wl,--gc-sections -Wl,-s -Wl,-subsystem,console -o ..\..\..\bin\qdoc.exe object_script.qdoc.Release  -LC:/OpenSSL-Win32 -LD:/Qt/icu/lib -LD:/Qt/static/src/qt-everywhere-opensource-src-5.5.0/qtbase/lib -lQt5Xml -lQt5Core -lole32 -luuid -lws2_32 -ladvapi32 -lshell32 -luser32 -lkernel32 -lmpr -lsicuin -lsicuuc -lsicudt -lqtpcre
mingw32-make[3]: Entering directory 'D:/Qt/static/src/qt-everywhere-opensource-src-5.5.0/qtbase/src/gui'
D:/Qt/Tools/mingw492_32/bin/mingw32-make -f Makefile.Debug all
D:/Qt/Tools/mingw492_32/bin/mingw32-make -f Makefile.Release all
D:/Qt/icu/lib\libsicuuc.a(putil.ao):putil.cpp:(.text+0x8d4): undefined reference to `localtime_r'
D:/Qt/icu/lib\libsicuuc.a(putil.ao):putil.cpp:(.text+0x8e8): undefined reference to `localtime_r'
D:/Qt/icu/lib\libsicuuc.a(putil.ao):putil.cpp:(.text+0x17e0): undefined reference to `dlopen'
D:/Qt/icu/lib\libsicuuc.a(putil.ao):putil.cpp:(.text+0x1840): undefined reference to `dlsym'
D:/Qt/icu/lib\libsicuuc.a(putil.ao):putil.cpp:(.text+0x1811): undefined reference to `dlclose'
```

I am using [this script](http://pastebin.com/hdR5dDaj) to build Qt. [There is](http://pastebin.com/UwurzjaE) a part of script output

Comment: You can't build static webkit.

Comment: @RazrFalcon I found alternative for webkit, webengine. Can I build static qt with webengine?

Comment: It's the same thing.